# making enums part of prop-types validation

Tags: react-native

In my component, I want a props to be an enum as follows:

```
enum choices {
wide,
medium,
small
}

interface props {
    size: choices
}


function SizeSelector({size}: props){
//...do stuff
}
```

then I want to do prop-types on it:

```
SizeSelector.propTypes = {
  size: PropTypes.oneOf(choices) //doesn't work
}
```

How do I make it part of the PropTypes validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  SizeSelector.propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.oneOf(['wide', 'medium', 'small'])
  }
```

Comment: that wouldn't work as is since type: choices in props.

Comment: @Hobo above code is shows how you can create enum in prop type.

Comment: For prop type enum you dont need to create `enum key {}` you need to pass array of string to `oneOf()`